# Why can't I restore MYSQL dumped file?

Tags: database, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have successfully created a MYSQL dump on windows

```
mysqldump -u myuname -p mydb > path/to/mydbdump.sql
```

I uploaded the `mydbdump.sql` to a live linux server, created a new database and trying to use these dumped data for new database

```
mysql -u myuname -p mynewdb < /path/to/mydbdump.sql
```

I get this error msg:

```
ERROR 1064: (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for for right syntax near '??' at line 1
```

I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong. Tried to restore this same file on a fresh database created on windows; didn't work.

**UPDATE:** First lines of dump file;

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `ep_categories`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ep_categories`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `ep_categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the first few lines of the input file?

Comment: You cannot restore your dumped file because you have an error in your SQL syntax. Open the file and see what's near `??`.

Comment: Can you show the first line or two of your dump file? Is your source system Windows?

Comment: Do you have a specific database selected like so:

USE database_name

Comment: I have updated OP with first lines of dump file.

Comment: I have a strong feeling of what the problem can be. Does adding `--default-character-set=utf8` when importing fix the issue? *(I hope this comment doesn't get ignored as my first one xD)*

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I did `mysql -u myuname -p mynewdb --default-character-set=utf8 < /path/to/mydbdump.sql`  Did not work.

Comment: And if you save the file as UTF-8 **without** BOM?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I don't even know what this "BOM" is, let alone configuring it. Struggling to read it up. Can you guide me on what to do??

Comment: @okeyxyz - I cannot tell you how to change the encoding in your editor because I don't even know what your editor is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it using suggestions from @ÁlvaroG.Vicario.

Problem was that the sqldump was encoded in `UTF-16 little endian`, so I re-encoded(using Notepad++ or linux `iconv` command) into `UTF-8 without BOM` and that solved it. I successfully restored sqldump into a new database server.

Comment: Notepad++ eats my entire file when I try to convert to UTF-8. Any trick I should be aware of?

Answer (score -3):

on ubuntu I simply do:

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -p < /home/userdir/mysql_dump.sql
```

then the prompt asks me for password and imports the .sql